# Rails: ActiveRecord query regarding size of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to figure out how to produce a certain query, using ActiveRecord.

I have the following models

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :limit, ...      
  has_many :employees
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

Each activity has a limit, that is to say, an integer attribute containing the maximum amount of users who may belong to it.

I'm looking for a way to select all activities that have spots available, i.e. where the number of users is smaller than that limit.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the SQL syntax to aim for would be:

```
select *
from   activities
where  activities.limit > (
         select count(*)
         from   users
         where  users.activity_id = activities.id)
```

In Rails-speak ...

```
Activity.where("activities.limit > (select count(*) from users where users.activity_id = activities.id)")
```

Not sure whether the column name "limit" is going to give you problems as it's a reserved word. You might have to quote it in the SQL.

I'd also seriously consider a counter cache for users on the activities table, which would make this perform much better. Some databases would support a partial index only for those rows where the users counter cache < limit.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! You're right about the limit column, and the counter-cache is a good way to simplify this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Activity.all.select{|activity| activity.users.length < activity.limit }
```

Comment: This could become *extremely* expensive if there are a lot of activities. Loading ActiveRecord objects is one of the most expensive things in a Rails app!